# Salvar TimeField em branco

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tenho uma função para salvar os dados importados do excel, o problema é que tenho um campo TimeField que pode vir em branco, e com isso tenho o seguinte mensagem:

> **Erro ao gravar objeto no banco:  ('expected string or bytes-like object',)**

```
#Função Importar Dados do Excel:
    def inventario_import(request):
    usuario = request.user.id
    print('Inicio de Importação Usuário: ', usuario)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_inventarios = request.FILES['myfile']
        df = pd.read_excel(new_inventarios)
        df.head()
        # print('Arquivo: ', df)

        today = date.today()
        # n = 0
        for index, row in df.iterrows():

            iip = ''
            field = ''


            col1 = row['SIGLA']
            col2 = str(row['LOJA'])
            col3 = row['DATA']
            col4 = row['TIPO']
            col5 = row['SETOR']
            col6 = row['PESSOAS']
            col7 = row['REGIONAL']
            col8 = row['LIDER']
            col9 = row['INICIO']

# Atribuindo hora de inicio
                    field8 = col9
#Função para Salvar
    inv = Inventario(loja=lj, dataInclusao=today, usuarioInclusao=us, dataInventario=field5,
                                         tipo=tp, horaIni=field8, setor=st,
                                         pessoasReal=field3, regional=rg)
    inv.save()
```

Eu tentei atribuir None dessa maneira no `field8` para resolver porém sem sucesso:

```
if field8:
   pass
else:
field8 = None
```

Alguém já passou por este problema e sabe como resolver ?

Obrigado.

```
#Campo do Model do Field HORA

    horaIni = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Rodolfo, você esqueceu de postar o código mais importante, o código do seu Model. Como você definiu seu TimeField? E seu código `field8 = col9` solto não serve pra muita coisa...

Comment: @fernandosavio Me desculpa, atualizei a pergunta, veja por favor se da pra compreender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depois de estudar um pouco eu consegui resolver esse problema usando o argumento try. Eu tento atribuir o valor, caso não consiga, ele salva os demais sem problemas.

```
invf = Inventario(loja=lj, dataInclusao=today, usuarioInclusao=us, dataInventario=field5,
                                      tipo=tp, pessoasReal=field3, regional=rg, id_pai=iip, filhoInventario=True)
                    invf.save()

                    try:
                        invf.horaIni = field8
                        invf.save()
                    except:
                        pass

                    invf.lider.add(ld)
```